# Is the fact that $g$ is defined from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ enough for me to claim the following?

Tags: functions, solution-verification

The questions was:
Given $f, g$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, proof or disproof that if
$f * g$ (or $f(g(x))$) is $*$on $\mathbb{R}$, then $f$ is on $\mathbb{R}$.

I wrote that the claim is true, citing that because $g$ is a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, then if $f$ wasn't on $\mathbb{R}$, $f * g$ would be undefined.

I am not sure whether this proof is valid or not.

$*$on is defined as:
function $f:B\to A$ is on group $A$, iff for a given $a\in A$, there is $b\in B$ such that $f(b) = a$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2130454/composition-of-two-functions-bijection  is a good proof of this, with more technical language.  If you need more help please ask.

Comment: @PaulBrennan thank you for the resource you provided!
but I am trying to understand weather I am missing something - is the proof, in general, correct?

Comment: I'm guessing that English is not your native language, and by "on $R$" you mean "onto $R$".

Answer (score 0):

Consider the functions $g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ You are asked if $f * g$ is on $\mathbb{R}$ if $f$ is onto $\mathbb{R}$.  So you are taking $g$ which is by definition on $\mathbb{R}$ and going to $\mathbb{R}$.  Does this seem to be evident by definition?  It does to me.